# Elastic Beanstalk Always Updates Environment On Deploy From Codebuild

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a large, multi-component django application I am trying to deploy to elastic beanstalk. I am using the multi-docker environment. THis is my current workflow

1. Git commit triggers AWS code pipeline
2. AWS Codebuild builds docker image (`docker-compose build`), runs some tests, and pushes this image to AWS Elastic Container Registry
3. AWS Code Build calls `eb deploy`

The issue I am running into is that when I call `eb deploy` from my local box, the it simply upgrades the application, but when I call it from Code Build, it is upgrading the environment every time, which takes about 30 minutes for some reason

I run the deploy command with `-v` and confirmed that the same files are being zipped. Any ideas on what is going on here, is my setup incorrect?

I also tried to deploy the application from Code Deploy in the pipeline and can confirm that it also always upgrades the entire environement.

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you use CB to update your EB env, it just replaces it as it is being considered as a new environment. In your local workstation you are using only one single environment, but with new application version.

I would consider replacing CB for updating your EB environment, with the EB deploy provider in your CP. This should successful just upload your new application version to an existing EB environment.

CP natively [supports a number](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/integrations-action-type.html#integrations-deploy) of deploy action providers, one of the being Elastic Beanstalk:

> You can configure CodePipeline to use Elastic Beanstalk to **deploy** your code. You can create the Elastic Beanstalk application and environment to use in a **deploy action** in a stage either before you create the pipeline or when you use the Create Pipeline wizard.