# Create an extra CDK CodePipeline Stage, deploying to ElasticBeanstalk

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

**Goal:**
A pipeline where I can have my code deployed to ElasticBeanstalk after all the infrastructure has been provisioned with CDK V2 (using TypeScript).

CodePipeline Stages should (happy to hear sugestions) flow like this:
**Source (Gets source code) >> Build (For pipeline infra) >> UpdatePipeline >> AppInfra (For ElasticBeanstalk infra) >> DeployAppCode (deploy the Artifact code from one of the earlier Build stages)**

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63404882/11131550) thread for advice on using CodePipeline instead of CodeBuild (which seems simple enough in console)
 and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59915417/how-to-give-particular-full-access-to-elastic-beanstalk-using-aws-cdk) as a model for how to set it up in CDK. Basically looks like "ElasticBeanstalkDeployAction" is the key, but also where my error is (doubt I know how it's used).

**Current code:**

pipeline-stack.ts (main CodePipeline setup)

```
import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { Construct } from 'constructs';
import { CodePipeline, CodePipelineSource, ManualApprovalStep, ShellStep } from 'aws-cdk-lib/pipelines';
import { Artifact } from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-codepipeline";
import { PipelineAppStage } from './stage';
import { ElasticBeanstalkDeployAction } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-codepipeline-actions';

export class InfraStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const pipeline = new CodePipeline(this, 'Pipeline', {
      synth: new ShellStep('Synth', {
        input: CodePipelineSource.connection('xxx/api', 'cdk-infra', {
          connectionArn: 'arn:aws:codestar-connections:xxx'
        }),
        commands: ['cd infra/', 'npm ci', 'npm run build', 'npx cdk synth'],
        primaryOutputDirectory: 'infra/cdk.out',
      }),
    });

    pipeline.addStage(new PipelineAppStage(this, 'prod', {
      env: { account: 'xxxxx', region: 'eu-west-2' }
    }));

    pipeline.addStage({
      stageName: "Deploy",
      actions: [
        new ElasticBeanstalkDeployAction({
          actionName: "DeployToEB",
          applicationName: 'Api',
          environmentName: 'Api',
          input: new Artifact()
        })
      ]
    })
  }
}
```

stage.ts (I define my stages from other Stacks here as a central place)

```
import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { Construct } from 'constructs';
import { EBStack } from './elasticbeanstalk-stack';

export class PipelineAppStage extends cdk.Stage {

  constructor(scope: Construct, stageName: string, props?: cdk.StageProps) {
    super(scope, stageName, props);

    new EBStack(this, 'EBStack', stageName);
  }
}
```

elasticbeanstalk-stacl.ts

```
import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { Construct } from 'constructs';
import * as elasticbeanstalk from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-elasticbeanstalk';
import * as iam from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-iam";

export interface EBProps extends cdk.StackProps {
  minSize?: string;
  maxSize?: string;
  instanceType?: string;
  envName?: string;
}

const apiName = 'Api';

export class EBStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, stageName: string, props?: EBProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    // Elastic Beanstalk Application 
    const beanstalkApplication = new elasticbeanstalk.CfnApplication(this, `${apiName}-Application`, {
      applicationName: apiName, // needed by "CfnEnvironment"
    });

    // Elastic Beanstalk Instance Profile
    const instanceProfileRole = new iam.Role(this, `${apiName}-AwsElasticBeanstalkEC2Role`, {
      assumedBy: new iam.ServicePrincipal('ec2.amazonaws.com'),
    });

    const instanceProfileManagedPolicy = iam.ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName('AWSElasticBeanstalkWebTier')
    instanceProfileRole.addManagedPolicy(instanceProfileManagedPolicy);

    const beanstalkProfileName = `${apiName}-InstanceProfile`

    const beanstalkInstanceProfile = new iam.CfnInstanceProfile(this, `${beanstalkProfileName}`, {
      instanceProfileName: beanstalkProfileName, // needed by "CfnEnvironment.OptionSettingProperty"
      roles: [
        instanceProfileRole.roleName
      ]
    });

    // Elastic Beanstalk Environment
    const optionSettingProperties: elasticbeanstalk.CfnEnvironment.OptionSettingProperty[] = [
      {
        namespace: 'aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration',
        optionName: 'IamInstanceProfile',
        value: beanstalkInstanceProfile.instanceProfileName,
      },
      {
        namespace: 'aws:autoscaling:asg',
        optionName: 'MinSize',
        value: props?.maxSize ?? '1',
      },
      {
        namespace: 'aws:autoscaling:asg',
        optionName: 'MaxSize',
        value: props?.maxSize ?? '1',
      },
      {
        namespace: 'aws:ec2:instances',
        optionName: 'InstanceTypes',
        value: props?.instanceType ?? 't2.micro',
      },
    ]

    const beanstalkEnvironment = new elasticbeanstalk.CfnEnvironment(this, `${apiName}-Environment`, {
      environmentName: apiName,
      applicationName: beanstalkApplication.applicationName || apiName,
      solutionStackName: '64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.5.8 running PHP 8.1',
      optionSettings: optionSettingProperties,
    });

    beanstalkEnvironment.addDependency(beanstalkApplication);

  }
}
```

**Issue:**
The following in 'pipeline-stack.ts' comes up with:
*"Argument of type '{ stageName: string; actions: cdk.aws_codepipeline_actions.ElasticBeanstalkDeployAction[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Stage'.
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'actions' does not exist in type 'Stage'."*

```
    pipeline.addStage({
      stageName: "Deploy",
      actions: [
        new ElasticBeanstalkDeployAction({
          actionName: "DeployToEB",
          applicationName: 'Api',
          environmentName: 'Api',
          input: new Artifact()
        })
      ]
    })
```

Comment: You don't need a deploy stage at all. You can just update your existing infra by updating `CfnApplicationVersion` property in `elasticbeanstalk.CfnApplication` object. Refer this tutorial https://www.buildon.aws/tutorials/deploy-webapp-eb-cdk#create-a-rest-api

Comment: That's what I was following for some of the steps. But I don't see the use of updating the Artefacts to S3 explicitly, I believe that is what the "CodePipeline" construct does anyways.
Following the docs, it looks like "[CfnApplication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_elasticbeanstalk.CfnApplicationVersion.html#sourcebundle)" accepts only explicit bucket names and key, while [Artifacts](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_codepipeline.Artifact.html) looks like it could do the same, just not sure how that all flows together.

Comment: Ok, what you can do is use  [Bundling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.BundlingOptions.html) feature of CDK. Build the application inside a docker container and use the generated artifact S3 object keys to update `SourceBundle` object.  Refer this blog post - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/building-apps-with-aws-cdk/. Use `s3_deployment.BucketDeployment` CDK construct to build your app.